# C# - How to convert 10 bytes to unsigned long

Tags: c#

I have 10 bytes - 4 bytes of low order, 4 bytes of high order, 2 bytes of highest order - that I need to convert to an unsigned long. I've tried a couple different methods but neither of them worked:

Try #1:

```
var id = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
```

Try #2:

```
var id = GetID(buffer, 0);

long GetID(byte[] buffer, int startIndex)
        {
            var lowOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, startIndex);
            var highOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, startIndex + 4);
            var highestOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, startIndex + 8);
            return lowOrderUnitId + (highOrderUnitId * 100000000) + (highestOrderUnitId * 10000000000000000);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting a 10 byte long? 10 bytes is 80 bits, which won't fit in a 64-bit long.

Comment: Last time I checked unsigned long was 64 bits wide. What do You expect to get? Are those terms You multiply by, in the last line supposed to be hexadecimal?

Comment: doesn't a long have only 8 bytes?

Comment: I know .NET version 4.0 was very recent when you asked the question, but with that you can also use the [`System.Numerics.BigInteger` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (requires reference to `System.Numerics.dll` assembly). Arrange your bytes in a `byte[]` and pass it to the constructor. To make sure the bytes are interpreted as an unsigned number, add an extra zero byte at the most significant end of the `byte[]` (`arr[10]` should be the `0` byte). Of course this approach works more generally than using `System.Decimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments indicate, 10 bytes will not fit in a `long` (which is a 64-bit data type - 8 bytes). However, you could use a `decimal` (which is 128-bits wide - 16 bytes):

```
var lowOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, startIndex);
var highOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, startIndex + 4);
var highestOrderUnitId = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, startIndex + 8);

decimal n = highestOrderUnitId;
n *= UInt32.MaxValue;
n += highOrderUnitId;
n *= UInt32.MaxValue;
n += lowOrderUnitId;
```

I've not actually tested this, but I think it will work...

Comment: I think you need to replace `UInt32.MaxValue` by `1m + UInt32.MaxValue` (two places).

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, a `ulong` isn't large enough to hold 10 bytes of data, it's only 8 bytes.  You'd need to use a `Decimal`.  The most efficient way (not to mention least code) would probably be to get a `UInt64` out of it first, then add the high-order bits:

```
ushort high = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
ulong low = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 2);
decimal num = (decimal)high * ulong.MaxValue + high + low;
```

(You need to add `high` a second time because otherwise you'd need to multiply by the value `ulong.MaxValue + 1`, and that's a lot of annoying casting and parentheses.)

Comment: Maybe it can be done with the `1m` literal which has type `decimal`. Then your last line would read: `decimal num = high * (ulong.MaxValue + 1m) + low;`