# How to convert ten bytes to floating point number

Tags: c, vb.net, binary, gnu

I have some legacy files that need mined for data. The files were created by Lotus123 Release 4 for DOS. I'm trying to read the files faster by parsing the bytes rather than using Lotus to open the files. I have value records of 10 bytes each.

@AndrewMorton from this [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55082159/2559297) pointed to http://www.mettalogic.co.uk/tim/l123/l123r4.html#rec17 It says we have a GNU Long Double which is 10 bytes.

He also pointed to [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/development.html) as they read WK3 files but I'm having difficulty finding the relevant code.

```
Dim fileBytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(fiPath)
Dim arr(10) As Byte
For ...
    arr(x) = fileBytes(x)
    Debug.Print(Convert.ToInt16(fileBytes(x)))
Next ...

'values to the right
Dim data1 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 17, 188, 22, 64}    ' Value = 12325165
Dim data2 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 248, 30, 196, 20, 64}   ' Value = 3213246
Dim data3 As Byte() = New Byte() {209, 92, 167, 145, 150, 202, 219, 205, 0, 64} ' Value = 3.21654
Dim data4 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 68, 196, 20, 64}   ' Value = 3215646
Dim data5 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 131, 211, 20, 192} ' Value = -3465434
Dim data6 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224, 131, 211, 20, 192} ' Value = -3465464
Dim data7 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 105, 163, 21, 192}  ' Value = -5354654
Dim data8 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 82, 74, 135, 24, 192} ' Value = -35465546

Dim data1 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 255, 191}                  ' Value = -1
Dim data2 As Byte() = New Byte() {205, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 251, 191}    ' Value = -0.1
Dim data3 As Byte() = New Byte() {10, 215, 163, 112, 61, 10, 215, 163, 248, 191}       ' Value = -0.01
Dim data4 As Byte() = New Byte() {59, 223, 79, 141, 151, 110, 18, 131, 245, 191}       ' Value = -0.001
Dim data5 As Byte() = New Byte() {44, 101, 25, 226, 88, 23, 183, 209, 241, 191}        ' Value = -0.0001
Dim data6 As Byte() = New Byte() {35, 132, 71, 27, 71, 172, 197, 167, 238, 191}        ' Value = -0.00001
Dim data7 As Byte() = New Byte() {182, 105, 108, 175, 5, 189, 55, 134, 235, 191}       ' Value = -0.000001
Dim data8 As Byte() = New Byte() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 255, 63}                   ' Value = 1
Dim data9 As Byte() = New Byte() {205, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 251, 63}     ' Value = 0.1
Dim data10 As Byte() = New Byte() {10, 215, 163, 112, 61, 10, 215, 163, 248, 63}       ' Value = 0.01
Dim data11 As Byte() = New Byte() {59, 223, 79, 141, 151, 110, 18, 131, 245, 63}       ' Value = 0.001
Dim data12 As Byte() = New Byte() {44, 101, 25, 226, 88, 23, 183, 209, 241, 63}        ' Value = 0.0001
Dim data13 As Byte() = New Byte() {35, 132, 71, 27, 71, 172, 197, 167, 238, 63}        ' Value = 0.00001
Dim data14 As Byte() = New Byte() {182, 105, 108, 175, 5, 189, 55, 134, 235, 63}       ' Value = 0.000001
Dim data15 As Byte() = New Byte() {188, 66, 122, 229, 213, 148, 191, 214, 231, 63}     ' Value = 0.0000001
```

I've tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831048/2559297) but it doesn't work; just gives garbage values (I tried both answers given).

How do I convert 10 byte GNU Long Double to Decimal. Since GNU is in C, I would welcome C code, but would prefer VB.net.

Comment: The answer you linked to isn't applicable because it is for an integer value. Could, you, ahem, ignore the smallest 16 bits?

Comment: You would ignore the two least-significant bytes. Figuring out which bytes they are would take a little research. I notice that in your edit you're using a UInt32, but a [long double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) is a floating-point type.

Comment: Those are 80-bit extended precision floating point values. The .NET framework doesn't support those, from I could find.

Most likely they have to be manually converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C code to build an array of ten bytes from ten decimal values and then interpret that array as a `long double` is straightforward if your compiler's `long double` implementation is compatible with this format.  The following program consumes ten decimals given on the command line.  Obviously it would be straightforward to obtain the numbers from somewhere else, perhaps from stdin or from a file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void
show_longdouble(const unsigned char array[]) {
    long double *ldp = (long double *)array;
    int ix;

    for (ix = 0 ; ix < 10 ; ++ix) {
        printf("%u ", array[ix]);
    }
    printf("=> %Lf\n", *ldp);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (11 == argc) {
        unsigned char vals[16]; /* only use 10, but dimension 16 for alignment */
        int ix;

        for (ix = 0 ; ix < 10 ; ++ix) {
            sscanf(argv[ix+1], "%hhu", &vals[ix]);
        }
        show_longdouble(vals);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program gives:

```
$ ./gnu-long-double 0 0 0 0 0 45 17 188 22 64
0 0 0 0 0 45 17 188 22 64 => 12325165.000000

$ ./gnu-long-double 0 0 0 0 0 248 30 196 20 64
0 0 0 0 0 248 30 196 20 64 => 3213246.000000
```

If you wanted to do the conversion manually instead of relying on the C compiler's built-in `printf` then the format is referred to in Wikipedia as the "x86 Extended Precision format" and is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format